# Possible to POST to a custom registered protocol/scheme?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, http, protocols

I'm developing a web application which is required to call a *custom registered protocol* on the clients computer.  Currently I do a GET to the protocol, which then passes the parameters via the querystring.

*Is it possible to do a POST to a custom registered protocol and if so how would I go about extracting the header information within CustomProtocol.exe?*

**This is my current GET solution**

To Initiate the call from javascript

```
Custom://startup?Function=DoSomething&Value1=Test&Value2=Test
```

The custom protocol that I registered onto my machine.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Custom\shell\open\command]
@="\"CustomProtocol.exe\" \"%1\""
```

I then compiled the below code to generate the CustomProtocol.exe.  During execution the URI is passed into the Main method, I then extract the querystring.

```
namespace CustomProtocol
{
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // Get the querystring from the URI being passed in
           // Business code...
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

This is the header when doing a post to the custom registered protocol.  The protocol only has 1 arg passed into it just like the GET which is the URI.  Somehow if I only were able to access the header information...

```
Request URL:http://localhost/CustomWebInvoker/Default.aspx Request Headersview source Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded Origin:http://localhost Referer:http://localhost/CustomWebInvoker/Default.aspx User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.78 Safari/535.11 Form Dataview URL encoded
        __VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUKMTkxMDU5NzI4OWRkBWZZppW219Muku6ZjiGZLQG5um8=
        __EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWCwKz9d77DAK57evuBgLk0vuTDALl+pjzDQKB8r3PAQKk+8X1CwLLneGNCgK2gO/LCAK355HvBAKAseegDAL+ovbYDMmmPuTHB0XbFjGRG9Wl1ij5kObV 
    dlLanguage:English  
    dlApplicationMode:UpdateMode 
    dlCallingApplication:CSS  
    dlCentre:EasternCompCenter  
    btnFastPath:Fast Path
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Gave it a go and added an edit above.  Same result, only the URI is the only argument passed and I'm so far unable to access the header information from within my CustomProtocol.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NO - any custom protocol handler is basically getting its information via the commandline... there is no way to map a POST to the commandline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)... IF you really need to do this I recommend implementing this as a http-based webservice (WCF, SOAP/REST)...

Comment: I was afraid this is the case.  I was hoping that I maybe overlooking something but I guess not.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @silentfrost you are welcome :-) There is one option to map a http request (GET/POST): you would need to implement your handler as a http "CGI-module" and integrate that into IIS or some other CGI-capable webserver (which is a rather old and unperformant way of handling http requests via an EXE).